# Lua Sqrt function inaccurate result

Tags: lua, sqrt

I use sqrt function on the number **500000**. But the result I get is **707.10681152344** which is a bit inaccurate because the correct number should be **707.106781187** (as google and any other calculator gives). Why is that so? I may miss something as I am very new to LUA. Thanks a lot

Comment: Strange indeed. I tried with Lua 5.1.4/5.2.3/5.3.0-work2 and got `707.10678118655`. Which Lua version are you using?

Comment: Maybe the floating pointer format used by Lua cannot represent this specific fraction. Perhaps you are using 32-bits or something.

Comment: @Havenard: Pretty sure that's not as rational as a fraction...

Comment: With a small C program, I get exactly `707.1068115234375` (consistent with your result) using 32-bit `float`. For 64-bit `double`, I get exactly `707.106781186547550532850436866283416748046875`. Apparently your Lua implementation is using 32-bit floating-point. As I understand it, it *should* be using double precision (64 bits); the implementations I have access to appear to work correctly. What system are you on?

Comment: I get 707.10678118655 using `print(math.sqrt(500000))` in the [Lua live demo](http://www.lua.org/demo.html).

Comment: I am using a lua program to script on an MMO game (afk training), don't know what lua version uses, and as I am using this function in-game I get those results

Comment: @darkchampionz: You can find out what version of Lua you're using by querying the predefined `_VERSION` variable.

Comment: godlike post sir, I get "Lua 5.2"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The result you're seeing is consistent with 32-bit floating-point arithmetic.

Lua normally use 64-bit double-precision floating-point (corresponding to the C type `double`), but according to [this link](http://www.lua.org/pil/2.3.html):

> It is easy to compile Lua so that it uses another type for numbers,
>   such as longs or single-precision floats. This is particularly useful
>   for platforms without hardware support for floating point. See the
>   distribution for detailed instructions.

Apparently that's just the way the Lua implementation  you're using was configured.